# how to forcefully sync the code using p4 sync in ant script

Tags: ant, perforce

I am writing an Ant script where I want to forcefully sync the client workspace from depot. Below is the code snippet that I am using, but I am not able to figure it out , how to use the flag -f in the xml. Can some please help me?

```
    <target name="sync_head_sql" description="Sync the workspace with head sql">
   <taskdef name="p4sync" classname="com.perforce.p4java.ant.tasks.SyncTask"    classpathref="p4_classpath"/>
    <p4sync
    files="//pay_import2/pay/wup2-parent/WU_DEV_ABCD_JBOSS62_V2_594_3/data- engine/conf/..."                                
    user="abcd"
    port="xx.xx.xx.xx:1669"
    client="wp-nagiosmon">
    </p4sync>
    </target>
```

The code mentioned above is able to sync the code successfully, but wants to know about the option of force sync. If i want to add in the above code, then how to do that? Where should i use the -f flag?

Thanks,
Faraz

Answer (score 1):

You can add the `force` flag into your `p4sync` tag like this:

```
   <p4sync
    files="//pay_import2/pay/wup2-parent/WU_DEV_ABCD_JBOSS62_V2_594_3/data- engine/conf/..."    
    force="true"                        
    user="abcd"
    port="xx.xx.xx.xx:1669"
    client="wp-nagiosmon">
```